# Difference time between two string not time of day in vba

Tags: vba, time, duration

I don't find a solution for this problem, I have two string with this format :

```
string1 = "23:19:03" (hh:mm:ss)
string2 = "27:08:03" (hh:mm:ss)
```

I'll need calculate time difference between this two string like

```
string1 = "23:19:03" 
string2 = "27:08:03" 
diff = 3:49:00   (h:m:s)
```

**UPDATE**
**I found a solution :**

fell free to use my code with mention me, thanks

```
Public Function timediff(ByVal time1 As String, ByVal time2 As String) As String
'Author: © Copyright 2017 Audisio Francesco **************************
'Description: Time diffence betweem two string no time of day!!,the format of this two string is ([h]:mm:ss) like excel function
'             time2 must be greater than time1
Dim ore1, ore2, min1, min2, sec1, sec2, tot1, tot2, tot, ore, apsec, min, sec As Double
Dim aladin1() As String
Dim aladin2() As String
'Dim time1, time2 As String
'genero secondi totali
aladin1 = Split(time1, ":")
    ore1 = Val(aladin1(0)) 'Ore
    ore1 = ore1 * 3600
    min1 = Val(aladin1(1)) 'minuti
    min1 = min1 * 60
    sec1 = Val(aladin1(2)) 'secondi
    sec1 = sec1
aladin2 = Split(time2, ":")
    ore2 = Val(aladin2(0)) 'Ore
    ore2 = ore2 * 3600
    min2 = Val(aladin2(1)) 'minuti
    min2 = min2 * 60
    sec2 = Val(aladin2(2)) 'secondi
    sec2 = sec2
'prendo i totali
tot1 = ore1 + min1 + sec1
tot2 = ore2 + min2 + sec2
tot = tot2 - tot1

ore = Int(tot / 3600)
apsec = tot - (3600 * ore)
min = Int(apsec / 60)
sec = apsec - (min * 60)
result = (ore & ":" & min & ":" & sec)
timediff = result
End Function
```

Use:

```
string1 = "23:19:03" 
string2 = "27:08:03"
ore1 = timediff(time1, time2)
ore1 = 3:49:0
```

Comment: Convert the string into time, take the diff and format the diff into "hh:mm:ss" format.

Comment: I am not familiar with the time `"27:08:03"` , something new ?

Comment: is  not time of day, this two strings are counter duration formatted in "hh:mm:ss", @Pratham is not possible to convert in time because is not a time of a day =D

Comment: @ShaiRado - I think the Excel format is `[h]:mm:ss`, which can display total hours > 1 day.

Comment: @Joe is it possible to have format [h]:mm:ss like excel into vba? yes if you put function = TEXT(D5-D4;"[h]:mm:ss") you have 3:49:00  as output

Answer (score 0):

you could use this helper function

```
Function GetDiffTime(string1 As String, string2 As String) As String
    GetDiffTime = GetTime(GetSeconds(string2) - GetSeconds(string1))
End Function
```

which, on its turn, uses the following functions:

```
Function GetTime(seconds As Long) As String
    Dim rest As Long

    rest = seconds \ 3600
    GetTime = GetTime & Format(rest, "00")
    seconds = seconds - rest * 3600

    rest = seconds \ 60
    GetTime = GetTime & ":" & Format(rest, "00")
    seconds = seconds - rest * 60

    GetTime = GetTime & ":" & Format(seconds, "00")
End Function

Function GetSeconds(strng As String) As Long
    Dim timeParts As Variant
    Dim iPart As Integer

    timeParts = Split(strng, ":")
    For iPart = UBound(timeParts) To LBound(timeParts) Step -1
        GetSeconds = GetSeconds + CInt(timeParts(iPart)) * 60 ^ (UBound(timeParts) - iPart)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: You are welcome. Given no built-in time function could be used, the 1-60-3600 splitting was the only way to go. My solution implements it with a special eye to code reusability and maintenance. Should you appreciate and adopt it, then you may also want to mark this answer as accepted. Thank you!